# Firebug only breaks on the first breakpoint

Tags: firefox, firebug, breakpoints

I've got Firefox 4.0.1 with Firebug 1.7.3 on Windows 2008.

To illustrate my point here's an example: http://jsbin.com/ihiduh/13

```
function start() {
   alert('in start()');  
   doWork();
}

function doWork() {
  alert('in doWork()');   
}

start();
```

When I put 2 breakpoints one in each of the functions firebug breaks on the first breakpoint  (in `start()`). I hit F8 (continue), dismiss the alert and expect it it break in `doWork()` on the second break point. The alert from `doWork()` does appear but Firebug doesn't break on the breakpoint in `doWork()`.
When I remove the breakpoint from `start()` it does break on the breakpoint in `doWork()`. Looks like it only breaks on the first breakpoint.

How do I make Firebug break on all breakpoints? (I suppose Continue should take me to the next breakpoint)

Comment: You are 5 major versions behind on Firefox and 2 minor versions on Firebug.

Comment: Wow! I'm surprised they moved 5 major version is such a short time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the keyword `debugger;` directly in your code.

Try to do something like:

```
function start() {
   debugger;
   alert('in start()');  
   doWork();
}

function doWork() {
  debugger;
  alert('in doWork()');   
}

start();
```

DON'T FORGET TO REMOVE THIS KEYWORD for production. It will raise a javascript error for IE for instance.